# FileNotFoundException in FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, .net, file, exception, file-watcher

I am using a `FileSystemWatcher` on a directory and added its event handlers, set its `EnableRaisingEvents=true;` and `IncludeSubdirectories=false;` and added `NotifyFilters`.

While running the application if I create new folders in the specified directory sometime I get

> FileNotFoundException : "An error occurred while reading a directory".
>   System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
>   System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)

What can be root cause of the problem?

What is `StartRaisingEvents()`?

Comment: Are you able to post the actual code.  I would guess that you are constructing the new folders paths incorrectly.

Comment: I am creating new folders using Explorer > Create New Folder

Answer (score 4):

Just out of stupidity, I googled it before thinking.

In my case, Path was being defined **after** EnableRaisingEvents.

e.g. won't throw an exception:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = @"C:\";
//...
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

This will:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
//...
watcher.Path = @"C:\";
```

So. since I like to fail-fast instead of letting the next one figure out what the hell is happening, I modified that after path declaration:

```
var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = @"C:\Users\me";
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(watcher.Path))
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"You must define a path.");
if (!Directory.Exists(watcher.Path))
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Directory {watcher.Path} does not exist.");
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Stupid issue, but at least I gave some quirky fail-fast solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is typically because the `FileSystemWatcher` can be unreliable.  The folder may not "fully" exist when you get the events.  You may need to retry with sufficient pauses and do various `Directory.Exists()` checks before actually performing IO operations.

Comment: I've had to put the thread to sleep to ensure that file has been successfully created before performing operations on the file.

Answer (score 2):

I've got quite the same problem and finally I found out that the problem was with the path.

The `Directory.Exist()` give answer that the directory exist... even if the path got a empty char in the end of the string but the `FileSystemWatcher` couldn't manage it.
So obviously the `Directory.Exist()` trim the path but the Watcher don't. In my case removing of the empty chars solve the problem.

Hopefully it could help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was some mystery where, I guess a directory was named with some invalid character(s). Directory.Exists(watchDirectory) would return true, but the FileWatcher would blow up with the error above.
The "fix" was to delete the directory and recreate it with the same name :)