# Why I'm getting FileNotFoundException while the file does exist

Tags: c#, streamreader, filenotfoundexception

I have a `FileSystemWatcher` which tracks if a new file is created. If yes I have a method which reads the file and does some things..
In the code below, I'm getting a `FileNotFoundException` but the path/file does exist! I already checked the path, the filename, etc. There's no clue why it doesn't find the file. 
Also in debug mode, I verified that the path variable has the right path but when I'm forcing it to continue, somehow it runs but unfortunately in release mode it stops..

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite), Encoding.Default))
{ 
    //my code
}
```

The error I'm getting is

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Could not find file
>   'myPathHere

Anybody can help?

Comment: Is the path definitely correct? If you copy and paste the path into Windows Explorer, does it appear there?

Comment: FileSystemWatcher can be twitchy. The file might not be there at the moment your code tries to open it. Have you tried calling File.Exists() before attempting to open it?

Comment: I think this could be a security thing as well, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10676402/704281

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8cb4ce0a-1c86-4564-9158-828115c7d6c2/filesystemwatcher-is-throwing-filenotfoundexception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976862/filenotfoundexception-in-filesystemwatcher

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, the path is correct and appears.

Comment: @KeithPayne This is what I had in mind, I think that Luaan's answer might be the solution to my problem.

Comment: @Waescher I don't think that it's a security issue, because as I mentioned previously, if I force it to continue in debug mode, it recognizes that the file is there and works!

Comment: @ShekharPankaj thanks for the links! especially this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976862/filenotfoundexception-in-filesystemwatcher is identical to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileSystemWatcher` tells you when a file is created, yeah. But that doesn't mean the file is finished writing by that point - it most certainly isn't. When you're stepping through the code, you're giving the other process the time it needs to write and close the file - in the end, this is a concurrency issue, and concurrency issues tend to be hard to reproduce when debugging. The same way, by the time you get around to manually check, the file is long done - the problem is in the timing. And sadly, there is no way to use `FileSystemWatcher` to give you a note when the file is closed (and thus, ready to be used by your application).

You need to wait until the file is actually complete - a simple loop trying to open the file and waiting a bit when failing should work well enough :)

Comment: I think that you are right, temporarily the folder can't be recognized. I'll check your solution and get back to you

Comment: So, your suggestion helped me a lot. I put in the fileSystemWatcher an if (File.Exists(e.FullPath)){ myMethod()} and now it works properly! Thanks!